# Is there a Chinese name for the initiality theorem?

Tags: translation

This is a very specialized question.  There is a branch of mathematical logic called Homotopy Type Theory in English, and in Chinese 同伦类型论.  There is a Baidu page on it baike.baidu.com/item/同伦类型论.   A big current question in this field is in English the "initiality theorem."  In fact "initial" here is related to the idea of an initial object in category theory, and initial object in Chinese is often  初始对象.   But initiality theorem certainly cannot be expressed as  初始 定理 since that already means other things. I tried searching  同伦类型论 with initiality theorem and got no hits at all.

Can anyone tell me if there is a current standard Chinese name for this initiality theorem?

This kind of "initiality" is sometimes expressed as 初始性质 and that may be the closest i will get.  As I said, this is a very specialized question.  There may just not be any standard Chinese name for this theorem yet.

Comment: I know nothing about math but is it: 初值定理?

Comment: @user3306356 : 初值定理 usually refers to an initial value theorem from mathematical physics, unrelated to this initiality theorem.  So it would not be a good name for this theorem in logic.

Comment: "initiality theorem" only gets 489 hits on Google (for me), it doesn't seem like something well talked about in English - let alone Chinese.

Comment: "initiality theorem" may be "初等定理"

Comment: If it's related to [_initial algebra_](http://staff.ustc.edu.cn/~yiyun/chapter/chap2.pdf) [=初始代数], then it would feature 初始 and _theorem_ 定理.

Comment: @Michaelyus  Yes it is that sense of initial.  The universal property of initial algebras is sometimes expressed as  “初始性质."  After the comments here, and discussion with mathematicians I think the theorem does not yet have a standard name in Chinese.   “初始性质定理" could work.  I will see next month what one group of logicians in China thinks.

Comment: I can't even find initiality theorem on wikipedia. Why don't you start writing it on wikipedia and there will be discussion

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no standard name for this theorem in Chinese.

Comment: I second the suggestion of @wada - maybe the Wikipedia article should be started and it will become the community-led standard name!